# Windows boot mgr is missing

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

My Hard drive NTFS changed to file system RAW. It can not be opened. So I formatted it. After few seconds the computer restarted. An error occurred that "boot mgr is missing".

I reinstalled Windows 7 with Cd-Rom. But it is still not responding. 
Please help me to reboot my Windows 7 ultimate PC.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot using Windows 7 bootable CD and Choose option  Startup repair. After that go to Next Options Choose Command Prompt use the commands `bootrec /fixboot` and `bootrec /fixmbr` it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Hiren Bootcd and run mbr fix tool

```
C:> MbrFix /drive 0 fixmbr /yes
```